# Facebook PHP SDK upgrade from version 3.21 to Version 5.7.1

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, sdk, facebook-php-sdk

i was trying to upgrade PHP SDK for one of my Facebook App from the version 3.2.1 to the latest version 5.7.0. all the relevant changes like Login , getting user details are in place. but while i am trying to get user_id through the latest SDK, sometimes it returns my user_id but most of the time it returns 0, as a result my app keep on reloading due to authentication.. but i am supplying all required fields for authentication.. below are my implementation. i am banging my head for long time to fix this. Any help would be appreciated.

XXXIframe.php

```
<?php
require_once('facebook_apps/XXXX/vendor/autoload.php')

$facebook = XXXXFacebook::singleton($parentAppId);
$visitorId = $facebook->require_login();

$facebook->updateOAuthToken($visitorId);

?>
```

XXXXFacebook.php

```
<?php

session_start();
require_once('facebook_apps/XXX/vendor/autoload.php');

class XXXXFacebook 
{


    private static $k_instance;
    private $facebook;
    private $facebookCanvasHelper;
    private $facebookRedirectLoginHelper;
    private $signedreq;
    private $facebookApp;
    private $permissions;
    private $userId;
    private $scopes;

    public function __construct($app_id) {

        try {

        $this->facebookAppId = myappid;

        $this->facebookAppSecret = myappsecret;

        $this->facebook = new \Facebook\Facebook([
          'app_id'  => $this->facebookAppId,
          'app_secret' => $this->facebookAppSecret,
          'default_graph_version' => 'v4.0'
        ]);

        $this->facebookCanvasHelper = $this->facebook->getCanvasHelper();
        $this->facebookRedirectLoginHelper = $this->facebook->getRedirectLoginHelper();

         $this->scopes = ['public_profile','email','user_friends'];
        $canvasUrl = 'mycanvasURL';

        $this->facebookCanvasUrl = $canvasUrl;
        $this->appRoot = $this->config['root'];
        $this->userId = $this->facebookCanvasHelper->getUserId();


        } 
        catch(Exception $e) {
            }
    }

     public function getUserId()
    {
        return $this->facebookCanvasHelper->getUserId(); //This method i am calling from multiple places from different file, this sometimes returns coorect value, but most of the time it returns 0
    }

    public function get_loggedin_user()
    {
        return $this->require_login();
    }

    public function require_login() {
        if ($this->loginRes) {
            return $this->loginRes;
        }
        $this->loginRes = self::authenticate();
        return $this->loginRes;
    }

    private function authenticate() {

        $canvasUrl = 'MycanvasURL';
        $appId = self::getFacebookAppId();
        $root = self::getApplicationRoot();

        $this->userId = $this->facebookCanvasHelper->getUserId();


        // user's authentication
        if (empty($this->userId)) {

            $requestURI = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_URL'];

            $page = str_replace($root, "", $requestURI);
            if (self::startsWith($page, '/')) {
                $length = strlen($page);
                $page = substr($page, 1, $length);
            }
            $redirectUrlFB = $canvasUrl . $page;

            $auth_url = $this->facebookRedirectLoginHelper->getLoginUrl($redirectUrl,$this->scopes);

            echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">window.top.location = \"{$auth_url}\";</script>";
            exit;
       }
       return $this->userId;
    }

     public function updateOAuthToken($userid, $appId = null) {
        try {
            $graph = $this->facebook;

            if (is_null($appId)) {
              $appId = $this->appId;
            }

                $oauthExpireDate = strtotime($this->o_authexpiredate);

                $now = time();
                if ($oauthExpireDate < $now || !isset($integrationData->o_auth)) {


                     $access_token = $graph->getApp()->getAccessToken()->getValue();

                     $data_access_token = $graph->getOAuth2Client()->getLongLivedAccessToken($access_token);
                     $access_token = $data_access_token->getValue();
                     $expires = $data_access_token->getExpiresAt();

                     if(isset($access_token) && isset($expires))
                     {
                         if($expires > 7200)
                         {
                            updateOAuthToken($userid, $appId, $access_token, $expires);
                         }
                     }
                }

        } catch(Exception $e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don’t think the facebookCanvasHelper is supposed to work that way. It’s purpose is to get an access token and / or user information from the signed request - but that gets passed to your app only when you initially enter the canvas app iframe, it won’t exist any more once you start navigating around in your app inside the iframe. You should get the user id in that initial step, and then store it into the session, so that you can access it from there later.

Comment: Hi biruk1230
Thanks for the advise.. it helped a lot..